# Error running outguess on Linux terminal in windows

Tags: cryptography, windows-subsystem-for-linux, steganography

So far I was able to get outguess installed on my Ubuntu distribution running under WSL by running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-install -y outguess`. Both commands worked fine. After, I tried running `outguess -r input.jpg output.txt` and the error `Can't open input file 'input.jpg': fopen: Permission denied` shows. I've looked on google and a few forums but there is no definitive answer to this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Ubuntu terminal on Windows"?  You have this tagged "windows-subsystem-for-linux", so I just want to confirm that you mean the Ubuntu distribution running under WSL on Windows and not something else.

Comment: Also, please provide more details on what you tried.  "Running a test" probably isn't enough information for us to help you.  Include information on how you installed outguess and any other steps you have tried so far.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yea I do the Ubuntu distribution running under WSL, sorry I didn't really know what it was called. By running a test I mean that I ran 'outguess -r input.jpg output.txt'. Once I did that, that's when I got the error. I installed outguess by first running 'sudo apt-get update' I then ran 'sudo apt-install -y outguess'. That installed correctly (I think). So far (since I'm not too experienced in this field) I've checked forums for some answers. none of them gave an answer to my problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info - I suggest you edit the question itself to add that to improve the quality of the question.  But I would also suggest that you post this over on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) as it is more a question about a tool than about a programming issue.